# What are the negative numbers to my tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging, reputation

What are the negative numbers to my tags? They don't correspond to my reputation or votes?
Sorry if its somewhere explained already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the total upvote(+1)/downvote(-1) score on questions or answers with that tag. The $\times$ number following it counts the number of questions or answers. Upvotes on answers count +10 reputation, and downvotes on answers count -2 reputation.  Upvotes on questions count +5 reputation, and downvotes on questions count -1 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse over the negative numbers it will tell you. Basically it means that some of your answers have received down-votes.